# Searching Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was wondering if there was a way to search an entire SQLite database for one specific word. I do not know the column that it is in or even the table that it is in.

The table and row/column that contains this specific word also contains the other entries that i need to edit.

In-short:

Need to find a specific word

Can't query (i don't think i can atleast) since i don't know the table or column name that its located in.

I need to know where this specific word is referenced. In what table and row so I can access the others that are along side it.

Basically, is there a CTRL+F functionality of SQlite that searches the entirety of the SQLite file?

I have mac/windows/linux machines. I am not limited by software if that is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any such functionality would essentially be running queries that check every column of every table. You can do that via a script that runs the following SQL:

1) Get a list of all the tables:

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'
```

2) For each table, get all of its columns (column name is available in the `name` field)

```
pragma table_info(cows)
```

3) Then for each table, generate a query that checks every field and run it:

```
select
  *
from cows
where name like '%Daisy%'
or owner like '%Daisy%'
or farm like '%Daisy%'
```